# guest owns NIC, host and other guests access via NAT

Tags: solaris, virtualbox, nat

OK, this is a bit complicated.  On my host OS, when Guest1 is running, I want any incoming connections to go to guest1.  So from the outside the system looks like guest1.  But I still need to access the network from the host, and guests 2 and 3.  Plus, if I'm remote, I need a way to get to the host from outside.  And if guest1 is NOT running, then networking needs to fall back to the host, so it's not cut off.

I've figured out that guest1 needs bridged mode. But how do i configure the host and the other guests to have NAT via guest1 instead of the host?  If I can do that, then I can set up a port-forward to ssh into the host.  But then how to make the host take over the NIC if guest1 is not up?

- Host solaris
- guest1 linux (redhat)
- guest2 win7
- guest3 - linux (ubuntu)

Comment: The normal way to use bridged mode is for both the host and the bridged guest to have their own IP addresses on the host's LAN interface. Other hosts can talk to either the host or the guest by using the right IP address. You say you _don't_ want this?

Comment: Right. Network infrastructure only allocates 1 IP address per system. Remote users should have network access to guest1, but not the host.

Comment: Well, hypothetically you could arrange to move a shared IP address between the host and the guest. I'd be amazed if you found an off-the-shelf solution for doing this. I would consider using NAT for the guest with port forwarding to make the guest accessible from outside.